# Magento 2: Impossible open Catalog -> Products

Tags: magento2

When I try open catalog --> Product list in backend:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to RLTS\Catingrid\Model\Category\CategoryList::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/app/code/RLTS/Catingrid/Model/Category/Categorylist.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): RLTS\Catingrid\Model\Category\CategoryList->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)) #1 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('RLTS\\Catingrid\\...', Array) #2 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Object in /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/app/code/RLTS/Catingrid/Model/Category/Categorylist.php on line 7
```

Any solution?

update

```
<?php

namespace RLTS\Catingrid\Model\Category;

class CategoryList implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
   public function __construct(
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
   ) {
      $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $collectionFactory;

   }
   public function toOptionArray($addEmpty = true)
   { 
      /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection $collection */
      $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
      $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');//->addRootLevelFilter()->load();
      $options = [];
      if ($addEmpty) {
         $options[] = ['label' => __('-- Please Select a Category --'), 'value' => ''];
      }
      foreach ($collection as $category) {
         $options[] = ['label' => $category->getName(), 'value' => $category->getId()];
      }
      return $options;
   }
}
```

Comment: could you please post your cunstructor code here.

Comment: @ Dharmendra Topic update

Comment: Have you tried clearing generated folder and cache

Comment: Priyank, you mean I should delete folder var/generation right ?

Comment: Yes you need to remove that.

Comment: I have rename this folder and then setup:di:compile but still this issue